# How do I determine if standard input is being passed to a Python script?

Tags: python

Some programs hang if they are executed by themselves on the command line such that they are supposed to be receiving input from standard input (i.e., `sed "s/test/text/g"`). How can a Python script determine if it is being passed data from standard input so an appropriate an error can be raised to avoid hanging for such input?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
import sys
if sys.__stdin__.isatty():
     print('Interactive')
else
     print('Non-Interactive')
```

Which produces the following output:

```
C:\>python bobo.py
Interactive

C:\>echo "test" | python bobo.py
Non-Interactive
```

See also [`os.isatty()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.isatty)